# Android App OrbBasic Persistent Memory

Tags: sphero-api

I am looking to get into loading OrbBasic programs into the persistent memory on sphero to allow them to run when the sphero is woken up. I have had luck loading programs into ram using the OrbBasicSample provided in the SDK, so I decided to try modifying the sample app to load the program into the flash memory instead. To accomplish this I changed from using the OrbBasicProgram object and it's methods, to the OrbBasicAppendFragmentCommand, OrbBasicExecuteProgramCommand, and OrbBasicEraseStorageCommand methods.

This resulted in the button pressed methods looking like this:

```
public void loadPressed(View v) {
    addMessageToStatus("Loading OrbBasic Program...");
    OrbBasicAppendFragmentCommand.sendCommand(mRobot, false, program);
}
public void abortPressed(View v) {
    addMessageToStatus("Aborting OrbBasic Program");
    OrbBasicAbortProgramCommand.sendCommand(mRobot);
}
public void executePressed(View v) {
    addMessageToStatus("Executing OrbBasic Program");
    OrbBasicExecuteProgramCommand.sendCommand(mRobot, false, 10);
}
public void erasePressed(View v) {
    addMessageToStatus("Erasing OrbBasic Program...");
    OrbBasicEraseStorageCommand.sendCommand(mRobot, false);
}
```

With the boolean value set to false, the program is loaded into RAM and runs as expected, when I change the value to true, it stops working altogether. Is there something I am missing to get the functionality I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently isn't supported in the released firmware (1.45).  We added it into the API/SDK because we knew we would support it at some point in the future. It will be in the next Sphero FW along with an increase in storage to 4K.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me on this.